# Migration from WLI to Human workflow

Tags: java, soa, jdeveloper, bpel, wli

while migration from weblogic WLI worflow to BPEL Human workflow, what is the option we have for jcx file for interacting with database.
any one please refer any document...
example; in my existing application we are selecting some values from database, in BPEL how we will achieve the same..

I am begineer in BPEL..

I have created a BPEL proces and data adapter inside that, now i want to execute that data adapter from my custom java code, is there any way to do the same.. pelase guide...
thanks

Answer (score 1):

What versions are you working with?  It is useful if you add more details about your set up.
Taking a wild guess, here is something that might help you:

Controls are exported as partner-links. The operations for this partner-link are derived from the methods in the control JCX file. Each method parameter is treated as a separate input message part; the name of the part is the same as the name of the parameter. The output message is determined from the return type of the control method. It has a single part called parameters, since a method has a single return type with no name.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs85/bpel/export.html#1061022

**EDIT:**

After a bit of research, I understand that you are on WLI 8.x. The link above should help you if you are facing problems exporting your JPD.
The alternate approach would be to import your 8.x project to 10g3 project, and export it from there. In this approach, you can generate BPEL2.0 compliant workflows. **Warning:** this is a one-time import, and the project will not be accessible via earlier WLI versions. So, try on a copy.

The second part of your question is not clear. **Invoking controls from your Java code would be the same as invoking a web service**. The WLI `control`s that are EJB calls/transformations get converted into web service `portType`s. You can consume these web services from your Java application (eg., using Axis.)

Eg: If I am trying to convert a JPD `SomeWorkflow.jpd`, and if my JPD (WLI 8.x) had a control

```
/**
 * @common:control
 */
private com.appmills.someapp.controls.TestDBCtrl dbctrl;
```

Or, alternatively with 10g3

```
    @Control()
    private com.appmills.someapp.controls.TestDBCtrl dbctrl;
```

The export creates three files `SomeWorkflow.bpel`, `SomeWorkflow.wsdl` and `SomeWorkflow_ctrl.wsdl`
The generated code would be:

```
<plnk:partnerLinkType name="com.appmills.someapp.controls.TestDBCtrl">
    <plnk:role name="control">
      <plnk:portType name="ctrl:com.appmills.someapp.controls.TestDBCtrlPT"  
                    xmlns:ctrl="http://www.bea.com/workshop/bpel/ctrl"/>
    </plnk:role>
  </plnk:partnerLinkType>
```

**EDIT 2:**
The generated WSDL for controls (in the above example `SomeWorkflow_ctrl.wsdl`) does not contain `<binding>` or `<service>` tags. These are left out for you to define. The assumption is that you have these available somewhere, and have to simply wire them in.

As you might be aware of, the JCX equivalents in Oracle-SOA are JCAs. There is no direct export-import between WLI and Oracle-SOA. This means that there could be varying amount of efforts based on your current code complexity and your migration plan.
In my opinion, for `JDBC Control`s specifically, the simplest solution is to rewrite them as `Database adapter`s.

Comment: Thanks for reply: I am using SOA 11.1.1.3, Jdeveloper 11g , weblogic 10.3.  I have created a process and have JCX files from my current project, now i need to implement same funcatinality in BPEL(that i have in WLI flow) I am copying my .jcx file  in my question post... now what steps i need to follow....

Comment: @Rozer Are your JPDs in WLI 10.3, or WLI 9.2?

Comment: Hi I tried to migrate be workshop from 8.1 to 10.3, but stuch while smart update. i dont have any credentials for login and neither got any offline patch ... except this one more favor i want as my jpd file will be bpel file and corresponding wsdl will be there so i can execute the process method through web service client from java code... but regarding partner links  that has been created on place of jpx file. how we will call them... it would be great if you give me lines of code or give me any effective links.. thks

Comment: Smart update is optional. If your company has a support account with Oracle, you could obtain a login ID/password. Will update my answer with additional information about export. Let me warn you, based on your schema+EDN compatibility, you might have to rewrite some JPDs.

Comment: @Rozer, I did update the answer, not very helpful, I believe. Once you get past your problems, please post your migration steps.

Comment: Hi, I migrated my JPDs to BPEL with the help of BPEL export utility and got list of files and many folders. important files are .BPEL, .WSDL, .componentType and composite.xml, for dbcontrol i have got a wsdl having all methods, but still not sure how i will use those methods. where is the implementation of those method(how bpel will associate with DB).. please help